# Is it queen of the south or Queen of Sheba in Luke 11:31 and Matthew 12:42?

Tags: matthew, luke, translation-philosophy

> Luke 11:31 The Queen of Sheba will stand up.

In the Greek manuscript Βασίλισσα νότου clearly indicates "queen of south". Some versions of the Bible have "Queen of Sheba". Are they not interpreting rather than translating the manuscript?

More importantly, why didn't Jesus say "Queen of Sheba"?

So the chroniclers call her "Queen of Sheba" in 1 Kings 10 and 2 Chronicles 9. Solomon somehow 'mistakes' her as a king of Sheba in Psalm 72. Jesus calls her "Queen of the South" in the gospels. I will ask her real name when I see her. Hopefully, she was not from Tarshish.

Answer (score 2):

First, the Greek text of Luke 11:31 and Matt 12:42 is "Queen of the south" in NA28, UBS5, Byzantine text, TR and all others that I inspected.  Further, UBS5 and NA28 list no significant variation in the Greek text in either Matt 12:42 or Luke 11:31.

"Queen of Sheba" is from the OT in places like: 1 Kings 10:1, 10, 13, 2 Chron 9:1, 9, 12, etc.

"Queen of Sheba" only occurs as an interpretive translation in versions like NLT, GNT, which do not translate the Greek so much as write what they believe the Greek writers intended.

As to why Jesus did not say, "Queen of Sheba" is not stated in Matt 12:42.  However, Jesus uses two witnesses against the "wicked and adulterous generation" (v39) - the men of Nineveh, the far north, and the Queen of Sheba, the far south.  Anything else is speculation because we are not told.

Comment: The Peshitta also has south.

Comment: Biblia Sacra Vulgata also has south.

Comment: @PerryWebb - many thanks Perry for checking this also.

Comment: Of course that's based on the best texts.  I did not look for variants, but so far we haven't found any.  It appears that the English translations based Queen of Sheba as = Queen of South base from OT.